# How to build Behavior Tree editor using WPF?

Tags: wpf, behavior-tree

We are going to develop a behavior tree editor using WPF.
However, we are totally new to WPF.
How to generate shape components that represent tree nodes and the components should be able to respond to mouse event like right mouse clicked.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for your tree. They get chosen automatically by classname. You can also specify one for your base type. Be sure not to use interfaces, but real classes.

So if you use different classes for your view models you can get along with something like this:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyTreeVariable}"
    SelectedItemChanged="MyTree_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" DataType="{x:Type self:MyBaseType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" DataType="{x:Type self:MySpecialType1}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" DataType="{x:Type self:MySpecialType2}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--- Triangle -->
                <Polygon Points="50,0 100,100 0,100" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

If you like to tell the different behaviors by data, you can use `DataTrigger` and `Setter`, but I`d recommend the way shown above.

Comment: But what we need is not a tree view but a CFG(control flow graph)-like view.

Comment: Be aware that a tree control is not suitable to display a not oriented graph.